# get target data for each dyad in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with people choosing their partners in a group.
It looks like that:

```
df<- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                income=c(100,200,300,400,500,600),
                chosen_group_member=c(2,3,1,3,1,2))

df
```

output:

```
  group income chosen_group_member
1     1    100                   2
2     1    200                   3
3     1    300                   1
4     2    400                   3
5     2    500                   1
6     2    600                   2
```

For each member I need to find his/her partners' income to get it as `target_income` variable:

```
  group income chosen_group_member target_income
1     1    100                   2           200
2     1    200                   3           300
3     1    300                   1           100
4     2    400                   3           600
5     2    500                   1           400
6     2    600                   2           500
```

Is there any way to do it in R with dplyr?
Right now I have only an idea to loop through each group, and for each member in each group to loop through all the members to look for their incomes, which is for sure a wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(target = income[chosen_group_member]) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: I am super grateful, that's a great answer! I wonder it makes sense to start a new thread, or I can ask it here: what is the similar way to count how many times a certain individual was chosen per group? let's say everyone in a group (apart from id=1) chooses individual with id==1, so if there are 5 members in a group, the counter should be 4. And if none has chosen him/her, the counter is 0. I guess it should be somewhat along the same line as your answer?

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski, try adding `count = sapply(row_number(), function(i) sum(chosen_group_member == i))` to the `mutate`